# Condition for changing a smart contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I'm developing an application using smart contracts. I wonder if it is possible to establish different states for a contract, for example:

User 1 determines a condition X, but also determines that user 2 can change this condition.
User 2 finds it necessary to change the conditions of the contract, so it changes condition X from the contract to condition Y.

In order to satisfy this situation I have considered using public key cryptography, where user 1 determines that certain private keys can make changes to the contract condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have a cryptography problem. Ethereum authenticates the sender for you. I think the trick will be formulating who can do what.

Here's an example interpretation of your description as I understood it.

There are n states, known by a topic ID. I made them bools for simplicity.

There is an "owner" who controls who else is allowed to edit the state. You could even make this ownership transferable but I left it out for brevity.

The owner is allowed to grant to revoke user access rights.

Certain users with permission from the owner can update a state.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Conditions {

    struct Topic {
        bool state;
        address owner;
        mapping(address => bool) canChange;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Topic) public topics;

    modifier onlyTopicOwner (bytes32 topic) {
        require(msg.sender == topics[topic].owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyTopicTrustee (bytes32 topic) {
        require(msg.sender == topics[topic].owner || userTopicPermission(topic, msg.sender));
        _;
    }

    function isTopic(bytes32 topic) public view returns(bool) {
        return(topics[topic].owner != address(0));
    }

    function userTopicPermission(bytes32 topic, address user) public view returns(bool) {
        if(!isTopic(topic)) return false;
        return topics[topic].canChange[user];
    }

    function createTopic(bytes32 topic, bool state) public {
        require(!isTopic(topic));
        Topic storage t = topics[topic];
        t.state = state;
        t.owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function changeUserAccess(bytes32 topic, address user, bool canChange) public onlyTopicOwner(topic) {
        topics[topic].canChange[user] = canChange;
    }

    function changeTopicState(bytes32 topic, bool state) public onlyTopicTrustee(topic) {
        topics[topic].state = state;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can a contract have two owners?

Comment: There's actually nothing special about "owner". it only gets meaning from interpretation in the contract code. It's a de facto standard but it can mean anything we want. Here, I made the contract itself has no owner, but the individual states each have an owner because someone needs the right to manage user access. It's just a sketch to give you some ideas.

Comment: In other words, `owner` is not a reserved word in Solidity. It's merely a variable name. It means whatever the contract says it means.